# ActionScript 3 - retrieving text values from TexInput created in component

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a tile layout containing a list of TextInputs and text fields , i have created these fields in a custom component using the following code;

```
var newTextInputs:Array = [];
        var newTextLabels = [];
        var space:Number = 30;
        var count:Number = 0;
        for (var i:String in columnsData)
        {
            //create text labels
            var label:Text = new Text();
            label.name = "label" + count;
            label.text = i;
            newTextLabels[count] = label;
            addChild(newTextLabels[count]);

            // create text fields
            var field:TextInput = new TextInput();
            field.name = "field" + count;
            field.width = 100;
            field.height = 25;
            field.text = columnsData[i];
            newTextInputs[count] = field;
            addChild(newTextInputs[count]);
            count++;    
        }
```

users are allowed edit the values in each TextInput field, now i need to retrieve the newly udpated values however how can i access these fields? Because the identifiers are created dynamically i cant simply go componentName.InputFieldName, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [getChildByName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName())

**later edit:** tested with Flash and TextField and it works:

```
trace(TextField(getChildByName('textfield')).text);
```

Comment: so do i need to specify the name of the textInput (eg field1) as the parameter and return a DisplayObject, how do i then use the display object to get the text values?cheers

Comment: try a typecast: TextInput(getChildByName('field'+i))

Comment: tested with Flash and TextField and it works: trace(TextField(getChildByName('textfield')).text);

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event handler for the TileList CHANGE event; when it fires, I think the event.target property will have the specific TextInput field. Alternatively you can look at the TileList.SelectedItem property.

You may also be able to have a DataProvider bound to the TileList instead of your code as shown, which will handle this automatically for you. Try just assigning your NewTextLabels array as the dataProvider.